# How to fix this? xampp phpmyadmin error

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

This is my logs. I just have this error when i try to run the phpmyadmin site

```
2015-07-27 19:28:56 1468 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-07-27 19:29:05 11d0 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-07-27 19:29:06 1468 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-07-27 19:29:06 1468 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-07-27 19:29:06 1468 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-07-27 19:29:06 1468 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-07-27 19:29:06 1468 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-07-27 19:29:08 1468 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-07-27 19:29:09 1468 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-07-27 19:29:09 1468 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-07-27 19:29:11 1468 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-07-27 19:29:18 1468 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-07-27 19:29:18 1468 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-07-27 19:29:19 1468 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.24 started; log sequence number 1665234
2015-07-27 19:29:19 1468 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-07-27 19:29:20 1468 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2015-07-27 19:29:20 1468 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2015-07-27 19:29:20 1468 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-07-27 20:00:35 8028 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-07-27 20:00:35 728 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-07-27 20:00:35 8028 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-07-27 20:00:35 8028 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-07-27 20:00:35 8028 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-07-27 20:00:35 8028 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-07-27 20:00:35 8028 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-07-27 20:00:35 8028 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-07-27 20:00:35 8028 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-07-27 20:00:35 8028 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-07-27 20:00:35 8028 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-07-27 20:00:35 8028 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1665234 and 1665234 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1665244 in the ib_logfiles!
2015-07-27 20:00:35 8028 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-07-27 20:00:35 8028 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-07-27 20:00:35 8028 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-07-27 20:00:35 8028 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2015-07-27 20:00:35 8028 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2015-07-27 20:00:36 8028 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-07-27 20:00:36 8028 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-07-27 20:00:36 8028 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.24 started; log sequence number 1665244
2015-07-27 20:00:36 8028 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-07-27 20:00:36 8028 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2015-07-27 20:00:36 8028 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2015-07-27 20:00:36 8028 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-07-27 20:01:43 4728 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-07-27 20:01:43 1ae8 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-07-27 20:01:43 4728 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-07-27 20:01:43 4728 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-07-27 20:01:43 4728 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-07-27 20:01:43 4728 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-07-27 20:01:43 4728 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-07-27 20:01:43 4728 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-07-27 20:01:43 4728 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-07-27 20:01:43 4728 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-07-27 20:01:43 4728 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-07-27 20:01:43 4728 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1665234 and 1665234 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1665254 in the ib_logfiles!
2015-07-27 20:01:43 4728 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-07-27 20:01:43 4728 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-07-27 20:01:43 4728 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-07-27 20:01:44 4728 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2015-07-27 20:01:44 4728 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2015-07-27 20:01:45 4728 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-07-27 20:01:45 4728 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-07-27 20:01:45 4728 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.24 started; log sequence number 1665254
2015-07-27 20:01:45 4728 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-07-27 20:01:45 4728 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2015-07-27 20:01:45 4728 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2015-07-27 20:01:45 4728 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-07-27 20:04:16 6740 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-07-27 20:04:16 1f18 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-07-27 20:04:16 6740 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-07-27 20:04:16 6740 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-07-27 20:04:16 6740 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-07-27 20:04:16 6740 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-07-27 20:04:16 6740 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-07-27 20:04:16 6740 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-07-27 20:04:16 6740 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-07-27 20:04:16 6740 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-07-27 20:04:16 6740 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-07-27 20:04:16 6740 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1665234 and 1665234 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1665264 in the ib_logfiles!
2015-07-27 20:04:16 6740 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-07-27 20:04:16 6740 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-07-27 20:04:16 6740 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-07-27 20:04:16 6740 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2015-07-27 20:04:16 6740 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2015-07-27 20:04:17 6740 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-07-27 20:04:17 6740 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-07-27 20:04:17 6740 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.24 started; log sequence number 1665264
2015-07-27 20:04:17 6740 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-07-27 20:04:17 6740 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2015-07-27 20:04:17 6740 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2015-07-27 20:04:17 6740 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-07-27 20:05:27 6580 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-07-27 20:05:27 1eac InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-07-27 20:05:27 6580 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-07-27 20:05:27 6580 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-07-27 20:05:27 6580 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-07-27 20:05:27 6580 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-07-27 20:05:27 6580 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-07-27 20:05:27 6580 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-07-27 20:05:27 6580 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-07-27 20:05:27 6580 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-07-27 20:05:27 6580 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-07-27 20:05:27 6580 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1665234 and 1665234 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1665274 in the ib_logfiles!
2015-07-27 20:05:27 6580 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-07-27 20:05:27 6580 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-07-27 20:05:27 6580 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-07-27 20:05:27 6580 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2015-07-27 20:05:27 6580 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2015-07-27 20:05:29 6580 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-07-27 20:05:29 6580 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-07-27 20:05:29 6580 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.24 started; log sequence number 1665274
2015-07-27 20:05:29 6580 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-07-27 20:05:29 6580 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2015-07-27 20:05:29 6580 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2015-07-27 20:05:29 6580 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-07-27 20:06:28 6940 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-07-27 20:06:28 1ac0 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-07-27 20:06:28 6940 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-07-27 20:06:28 6940 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-07-27 20:06:28 6940 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-07-27 20:06:28 6940 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-07-27 20:06:28 6940 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-07-27 20:06:28 6940 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-07-27 20:06:28 6940 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-07-27 20:06:28 6940 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-07-27 20:06:29 6940 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-07-27 20:06:29 6940 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1665234 and 1665234 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1665284 in the ib_logfiles!
2015-07-27 20:06:29 6940 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-07-27 20:06:29 6940 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-07-27 20:06:29 6940 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-07-27 20:06:29 6940 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2015-07-27 20:06:29 6940 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2015-07-27 20:06:30 6940 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-07-27 20:06:30 6940 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-07-27 20:06:30 6940 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.24 started; log sequence number 1665284
2015-07-27 20:06:30 6940 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-07-27 20:06:30 6940 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2015-07-27 20:06:30 6940 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2015-07-27 20:06:30 6940 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-07-27 20:14:30 4400 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-07-27 20:14:30 1134 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-07-27 20:14:30 4400 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-07-27 20:14:30 4400 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-07-27 20:14:30 4400 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-07-27 20:14:30 4400 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-07-27 20:14:30 4400 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-07-27 20:14:30 4400 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-07-27 20:14:31 4400 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-07-27 20:14:31 4400 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-07-27 20:14:31 4400 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-07-27 20:14:31 4400 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1665234 and 1665234 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1665294 in the ib_logfiles!
2015-07-27 20:14:31 4400 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-07-27 20:14:31 4400 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-07-27 20:14:31 4400 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-07-27 20:14:31 4400 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2015-07-27 20:14:31 4400 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2015-07-27 20:14:35 4400 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-07-27 20:14:35 4400 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-07-27 20:14:35 4400 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.24 started; log sequence number 1665294
2015-07-27 20:14:35 4400 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-07-27 20:14:35 4400 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2015-07-27 20:14:35 4400 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2015-07-27 20:14:35 4400 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-07-27 20:17:30 1524 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-07-27 20:17:30 1290 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-07-27 20:17:30 1524 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-07-27 20:17:30 1524 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-07-27 20:17:30 1524 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-07-27 20:17:30 1524 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-07-27 20:17:30 1524 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-07-27 20:17:30 1524 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-07-27 20:17:30 1524 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-07-27 20:17:30 1524 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-07-27 20:17:31 1524 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-07-27 20:17:31 1524 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1665234 and 1665234 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1665304 in the ib_logfiles!
2015-07-27 20:17:31 1524 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-07-27 20:17:31 1524 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-07-27 20:17:31 1524 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-07-27 20:17:31 1524 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2015-07-27 20:17:31 1524 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2015-07-27 20:17:32 1524 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-07-27 20:17:32 1524 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-07-27 20:17:32 1524 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.24 started; log sequence number 1665304
2015-07-27 20:17:32 1524 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-07-27 20:17:32 1524 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2015-07-27 20:17:32 1524 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2015-07-27 20:17:32 1524 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

can somebody here can help me out?
and this is the error in the phpmyadmin http://prntscr.com/7xj7wg
and after opening the localhost/phpmyadmin suddenly the mysql in the xampp was closed

Comment: It is not an error. FEDERATED storage engine was not started. What is the version of your MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of your MySQL? It is not an error. FEDERATED storage engine was not started in your mysql server. It is not important to consider.

However I suggest you use MySQL 5.0.3 or more to overcome this issue.

Some useful information about [FEDERATED storage engine.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html)